# Is the compiler allowed to omit non-virtual private member functions?

Tags: c++

If i have a simple class like this

```
class A {
    void private_function();
public:
    void public_function() { /* calls the private function in here */ }
};
```

Is the compiler required to emit object code for private_function(), or is it allowed to inline all calls to private_function() and to omit private_function from the generated executable?

Comment: Why would it matter what the compiler inlines? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Can you write a standard-conforming program that can tell the difference? If not, it's allowed.

Comment: @Pete: Sure, but since there's an infinite number of standard-conforming programs that behave in intricate and sometimes arcane   ways, its hard to give an answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the compiler required to emit object code for `private_function()`

It will have to if anything uses its address.

> or is it allowed to inline all calls to `private_function()` and to omit `private_function` from the generated executable?

If nothing uses its address, yes. The program's behaviour would be identical whether or not it generated an unused non-inline version; so by the "as if" rule, it's free not to generate it.

Comment: Could you point me towards the exact definition of odr-used?

Comment: @Benno: C++11 3.2/2. Though I may have misused the term here - it's *odr-used* if you call it, but you only need a non-inline definition if you take its address.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I believe it is perfectly legal to take the address of an inline function, is it not?

Comment: @SamCristall: It certainly is. If you do, then the compiler will have to generate a non-inline version, so that it has an address. If you don't, then it's free no to.

Comment: Is it possible for code outside of A to take the adress of private_function, or can this only happen within A?

Comment: @Benno: Since it's private, you have to be inside a member or friend of `A`.

Comment: Or someone did a `#define private public`. What if you have that define in a header for the include of a dynamic linked library, and not in library build?

Comment: @BeniBela: Then you've broken the One Definition Rule, and you've got undefined behaviour.